# Do all atoms in a plasma react to magnetism or just the ionized ones?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics

when I have a plasma with a low ionization, what atoms react to magnetism?

Comment: The trajectories of charged particles are influenced by the magnetic fields, see [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). The ones of neutral atoms not. So if you have a plasma with a low degree of ionization, its only the electrons' and ions' trajectories which are influenced by the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All atoms which are ionized (and moving) will react to magnetism via the Lorentz force,

$$\vec{F} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B}$$

it doesn't matter the species or how low their ionization may be.

Neutral atoms in the plasma will only interact as part of the plasma through collisional processes, mainly with other ions.